# WCF Service: Publicly available services useful for testing

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, public

I need a public WCF service to test against. I would like some basic methods to call. What service should I use. (sidenote: how do I search for publicly available services?)

Im trying this out : [sudz code generator](http://sudzc.com/) and I don't want to have to setup a publicly available service just to test it

Comment: Is there some reason you can't run your tests against a local service? Reasoning behind this would give the question more weight.

Comment: @Peter - Do you actually have an answer?

Comment: @Aran, sorry you feel that way, but nothing about what you asked actually requires the service to be public. Sudz merely requires access to the WSDL. You could just as easily have created a simple service, posted the WSDL somewhere, and generated code from that.

Comment: @Peter. SO's aim is to become the definitive answer set. It was of interest to me to find publicly available web services, and in the future I'm sure this will be useful to others. Here we answer questions even if they are someones homework, because having a repository of all programming related questions and answers makes everyones life easier. Your above comment is correct about sudzc's operation and that comment would have made a good answer. However when someone searches for "find publicly available web services" this answer here will be useful. Your original comment won't be.

Comment: Last comment from me - I wouldn't have been able to answer with that had you not responded to my comment. So does the comment really detract from the question? I wasn't trying to be snippy - I just didn't understand what specific value the service being public has in this situation. It's very hard to answer a question correctly if you don't fully understand it.

Comment: And this is a perfectly good example of a good question which COULD USE SOME ANSWERS, except some **** marked it as off-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this as well
http://www.xmethods.net/ve2/index.po

Answer (score 8):

I was looking for some myself and wanted to make sure they were WCF.  I found the [Bing Maps SOAP Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966738.aspx).  In case that link expires, below are the service URLs.

The downside is that you need to create a Bing Maps key and pass it in the web service requests.  Trial keys last 90 days.  Instructions for generating keys are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428642.aspx).

[Geocode Service](http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocodeservice/geocodeservice.svc)

[Imagery Service](http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/imageryservice/imageryservice.svc)

[Route Service](http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/routeservice/routeservice.svc)

[Search Service](http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/searchservice/searchservice.svc)

Answer (score -1):

if you want to test already hosted wcf service, follow below url , their you can find few wcf services those are already hosted in online, just you need to consume those services in your application only

http://aspdotnetfiddle.com/Home/WcfServices

Comment: Same response as SriramNidamanuri. According to @RadimKöhler I flagged.

Comment: No longer relevant. Domain is hosting ads now.

Answer (score -2):

try this uri
http://www.soapclient.com/uddisearch.html
this is basically for WebServices but you can use them in WCF  as well